# C++ Compiler Alignment - Just chars no padding

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, padding, memory-alignment

On VC++, why does the compiler only pad struct when non-char datatypes are used?

I.e.

```
struct TEST
{
   char a[7];
};

struct TEST2
{
   __int32 a;
   char b[7];
};

sizeof(TEST); // Returns 7
sizeof(TEST2); // Returns 12
```

Comment: This is completely compiler-specific.  What compiler are you testing this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to the fact that `sizeof(char) == 1` -- always.

Arrays are required to be contiguous, so in an array of char (if it's large enough), you end up with elements at every possible alignment. Since the compiler/hardware *has* to make that work, there *can't* be a need to insert padding to deal with `char` in something like a `struct` either.

Now, that's not to say that a compiler *couldn't* insert padding. For example, it might be able to improve performance by doing so, even with an array of char. For example, given your `struct` definition, it would be perfectly acceptable for the compiler to pad your array of 7 char's with one more to make the sizeof the struct 8 -- a nice, neat power of 2.

On some hardware, you'd be likely to see that. As it happens, the Intel hardware supported by VC++ doesn't really benefit much from things like that, so you're unlikely to see it there.

Comment: That makes sense. The same works without a char array (i.e. `char c1, c2, ...`).

Comment: @Di-0xide: Not really -- two separately defined `char`s are not required to be contiguous. In an array they *must* be contiguous though (e.g., if the first char in an array is at xxxx0, then the next one *must* be at xxxx1).

Comment: Oh interesting - no I was referring to the padding the compiler performs. I received the same test results, at least in this scenario.

Comment: @Di-0xide: It's not surprising to see the same (especially on Intel hardware), but in this case it *could* insert padding between them if it wanted, whereas in an array it's not allowed to.